# Synchronous sleep in async execution?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Is there a way to somehow create a way to sleep in a executing function that is async to mimic a thread.sleep?

For example I have

```
 Workthread run()
 {
 while (true)
 {
 //All calls cannot pause inside, async
 CallWorkFunction();
 CallOtherWorkFuctuion();
 Callthirdworkfunction();
 thread.sleep(0x10);
  curtick++;
 }
 }

//CallWorkFunction()

if (nexttick - curtick > 0)
   return;
foreach (var item in collection.ToList())
{
   if (!item.IsReady)
       continue;
   collection.Remove(item);
   ProcessItem(item);
   nexttick = curtick + 20;
   return;
}
```

This function would work so much more better if the `nexttick` can work like a thread `Thread.Sleep()` without stopping the execution. As the async code is turning out to have a bunch of state-based checks, many of which can be replaced with correct pauses.

Comment: Are you trying to poll something every 16 milliseconds? Your `run()` method looks like it should be a timer rather than a sleep loop. Come to think of it, the whole thing looks like it should be on a timer. It's hard to tell for sure without more context, though.

Comment: If you're using async/await, you can await `Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
async Workthread run()
{
    while (true)
    {
     //All calls cannot pause inside, async
     CallWorkFunction();
     CallOtherWorkFuctuion();
     Callthirdworkfunction();

     await Task.Delay(0x10);

     curtick++;
    }
}
```